# GitLAB Dedicate Runner not able to contact pull docker image

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

GitLab dedicated runner defined in the Yaml file using the Tags..But the pre build failing due to not able to pull the docker image defined "amazonlinux:latest",,,,FYI below is where the runner is stuck.....

Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343)
on runner1 xyzf
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor

If any experts out there, looking for your valueable suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check whether the user with which you are running the runner has access to run docker commands

Comment: Thanks for the input..But i have sorted out on that day itself, the issue was, runner ec2 instance was not able to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input..But i have sorted out on that day itself, the issue was, runner ec2 instance was not able to be created due to subnet issue.